# CSS and JS files are not loaded from cache

Tags: javascript, c#, css, browser-cache

Why wouldn't my JS and CSS files load from cache?
See below, all these requests for the CSS files are not being read from cache.
I don't see anything out of the ordinary when I expand one of the requests (second screenshot).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: When you work with the developer tools open sometimes you check "Disable cache" on the network tab. try to uncheck it and see if it solves your problem

Comment: I can confirm that it is unchecked

Comment: I am not a cache expert. But are you sure its not using cache? If changing content in one of the JS files, does your response from that file return the updated content or the old content?

Comment: Its normal because in every request you put a new path yu have to remove the get parameter ?v=.....

Comment: The path stays unchanged, it is a static version value across all the requests.